# Need hints on seemingly simple SQL query

Tags: sql, select, count, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to do something like:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, COUNT(orders.id)
FROM customers c
JOIN orders o ON o.customerId = c.id
```

However, SQL will not allow the COUNT function. The error given at execution is that c.Id is not valid in the select list because it isn't in the group by clause or isn't aggregated.

I think I know the problem, COUNT just counts **all** the rows in the `orders` table. How can I make a count for each customer?

## EDIT

Full query, but it's in dutch... This is what I tried:

```
select k.ID,
       Naam,
       Voornaam,
       Adres,
       Postcode,
       Gemeente,
       Land,
       Emailadres,
       Telefoonnummer,
       count(*) over (partition by k.id) as 'Aantal bestellingen',
       Kredietbedrag,
       Gebruikersnaam,
       k.LeverAdres,
       k.LeverPostnummer,
       k.LeverGemeente,
       k.LeverLand
from klanten k
  join bestellingen on bestellingen.klantId = k.id
```

No errors but no results either..

Comment: You need `GROUP BY c.id, c.name` at the end of a query.

Comment: You're also missing an alias on the `orders` table (the above query can't possibly compile). And this is leading all the answers to have invalid syntax as well.

Comment: @AaronBertrand that was unintentional, fixed now.

Comment: Strongly recommend not using `'single quotes'` for column/object aliases; this syntax has been deprecated. Use `[square brackets]` or, if you must use quotes, `"double quotes"`. Or better yet, avoid aliases that require delimiters in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to be able to select all of the columns in `Customers` without specifying the names ([please read this blog post in full](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list) for reasons to avoid this, and easy workarounds), then you can do this lazy shorthand instead:

```
;WITH o AS 
(
  SELECT CustomerID, CustomerCount = COUNT(*)
  FROM dbo.Orders GROUP BY CustomerID
)
SELECT c.*, o.OrderCount
FROM dbo.Customers AS c
INNER JOIN dbo.Orders AS o
ON c.id = o.CustomerID;
```

**EDIT** for your real query

```
SELECT 
  k.ID, 
  k.Naam, 
  k.Voornaam, 
  k.Adres, 
  k.Postcode, 
  k.Gemeente, 
  k.Land, 
  k.Emailadres, 
  k.Telefoonnummer,
  [Aantal bestellingen] = o.klantCount, 
  k.Kredietbedrag, 
  k.Gebruikersnaam, 
  k.LeverAdres, 
  k.LeverPostnummer, 
  k.LeverGemeente, 
  k.LeverLand
FROM klanten AS k 
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT klantId, klanCount = COUNT(*)
  FROM dbo.bestellingen 
  GROUP BY klantId
) AS o
ON k.id = o.klantId;
```

I think this solution is much cleaner than grouping by all of the columns. Grouping on the orders table first and then joining once to each customer row is likely to be much more efficient than joining first and then grouping.

Comment: Thank you, this works absolutely fine and it's a very neat query.

Answer (score 5):

When using an aggregate function like that, you need to group by any columns that aren't aggregates:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, COUNT(orders.id)
FROM customers c
JOIN orders o ON o.customerId = c.id
GROUP BY c.id, c.name
```

Comment: Is that REALLY necessary? Is there NO other way? I cannot do that cause I'm selecting pretty much all the columns and when I add them all to group by, the query doesnt return anything anymore.

Comment: @Mario then post your entire query, some sample data, and desired results. Typing out all the columns shouldn't be a problem - you can simply drag the `Columns` node from Object Explorer onto your query window. But you need to better define what your query is actually supposed to return.

Comment: @Mario - Unfortunately it is.  I know MySQL offers a shortcut where if you group by the primary key, it lets you exclude the other columns, but not in SQL server.

Answer (score 1):

The following will count the orders per customer without the need to group the overall query by customer.id. But this also means that for customers with more than one order, that count will repeated for each order.

```
 SELECT c.id, c.name, COUNT(orders.id) over (partition by c.id)
 FROM customers c
   JOIN orders ON o.customerId = c.id
```

Comment: "that count will repeated for each order." How to solve that then?

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester: then you'll need a `group by` as shown in the other answers